Changing the uniform distribution range of the Miller-Rabin primality test
When implementing the Miller-Rabin probabilistic primality test - determine if $N$ is likely prime; prior to running the test for performance and robustness reasons one typically uses a list of the first $K$-primes and verifies that none of those primes are factors of $N$.
Furthermore in the Miller-Rabin test there is a value generated by sampling a uniform random distribution in the range of $[2,N-2]$.

My question: If the first test is performed (List of K primes), would it be valid to change the range of the uniform distribution to $[P_k,N-2]$ ?

I think I misunderstood the question.


The Miller Rabin test also works without trial division , but it makes sense to begin with trial division if the number to be tested is huge and might be divisible by , say , $7$. 2. It is no good idea to restrict to bases greater than $P_k$. The more distinct bases are checked , the better. 3. You can start to check $gcd(b,N)=1$ , where $N$ is the number and $b$ the base. If the gcd is not $1$ , you can stop since $N$ cannot be prime.


A Miller-Rabin of the form MR(n,p), where n is the integer to test and p is some prime witness, does prove all n that are divisible by p (aka p | n) are composite. However, the majority of composites are also proven composite without needing this relation.
As an example MR(n,2) is quite strong, clearly it should be since half of all composites in some interval are  divisible by 2. But for all n > 10^12 MR(n,5) is stronger, as is MR(n,15) and MR(n,37), this is despite the fact that 3,5, and 37 are rarer factors within some arbitrary interval (MR(n,3) is not stronger than MR(n,2)). The MR test is so much stronger than trial division that selecting the base for common prime factors produces no improvement.
Likewise, starting your interval to not use the first several primes will also not affect the accuracy of your test, so long as you are still sampling from a sufficiently large interval. For instance if you are performing trial division by the first 64 primes (P >= 311) on a 64-bit number (N < 2^64), and you decide to search [312;N-2] where N > 311^2 (otherwise it would be factored by trial division); you have a minimum search space of 311^2-(312+2) = 96407. That gives you a minimum of 96407 possible witnesses to select from,and this is the worst possible case.  In general, this would simply reduce the search space from N-2 to N-2-the_largest_prime, which is negligible in the vast majority of cases.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.


It seems to be popular to chose a to be a prime number, and my
question is if there are rational reasons for that?

Not really, it is just a unproofed belief of many, that primes are better filters. In fact it shows that composites filter as good as primes and even better, and some few even very good. Using small bases, the composites 735 or 9375 for example filter very good. I made statistics in 2^64, the filter efficiency of bases show a typical bell curve, some very few are weak or strong, the most are average.
To use only static bases or even only small primes is a typical implementation error for Miller-Rabin.
It is recommended to use random selected bases, because if software uses only static bases, a attacker could make use of this weakness.
It is known how to create pseudo primes intentionally witch pass many bases, if only small primes are used.
A paper about prime test implementation issues.
https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/749

The paper was very informative! thanks for that.
